# Problem with making .exe from python file by PyInstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, exe, pywin32

My script .py work  perfectly, but .exe sadly doesn't work. Im running on newest PyInstaller.

[Here is my script](https://github.com/sat1ss/Printer_extension/blob/main/Printer_script.py)

I already tried everyting that i can think of here is options that i used:

[Options used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba1QY.png)

- **-w** : does't have .exe file
- **-- onefile -w** and **-F -w** : [The specified module could not be found.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3tTd.png)
- **--F** , **--onefile** and **no option used** : [Only shows this option for like half a second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6CrN.png)

Comment: There is no real question asked in here other than an implicit, how to fix it?
The "options" used section of the question is not really making the question any clearer. Please add the command that you are using to build and the error message you get, or the unexpected behavior. ".exe does not work" is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work around this issue by importing pywintypes into my script before win32print module.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Not all python code can be compiled into a .exe.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the case. I would really like to be able to make an exe out of it

Comment: I have built at least 8 projects with pyinstaller with very different imports, pandas, pyautogui, selenium, pyaudio, multiprocessing, among others. If a python project is not working with pyinstaller, in all likelihood, it is either because of it being an obscure case or because pyinstaller was not properly configured. That said, without any proof, this low effort answer is not helpful.

Comment: @ferreiradev like i sad in answear bellow problem was solved, it was caused by not imported pywintypes before win32print